# Apache ActiveMQ Artemis web console

Tags: activemq-artemis

Where can I find information about the web console of ActiveMQ Artemis 2.16.0?

[image]

i.e. What do these columns indicate? What is a rate? How it is calculated? Messages per second? Bytes per second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These columns refer to the queue's immutable configuration:

- Routing Type
- Filter
- Durable
- Max Consumers
- Purge On No Consumers
- Temporary
- Auto Created
- User

These columns refer to the queue's runtime state:

- Consumer Count
- Rate
- Message Count
- Paused
- Total Messages Added

Most of these columns are self explanatory (e.g. "User" is the user who created the queue (if any), "Consumer Count" is the number of consumers currently on the queue, etc.). If you need additional details then most of the immutable configuration elements are based on the matching `address-setting` described in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html#configuring-addresses-and-queues-via-address-settings).

The "Rate" column is an *internal* detail related to [slow-consumer detection](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/slow-consumers.html). It essentially represents how quickly messages are being added to the queue. This was never meant to be a user-facing metric, but it was mistakenly exposed via the management API via [ARTEMIS-2322](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2322) in version 2.10.0, a change which was then reverted via [ARTEMIS-2909](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2909) in 2.16.0. This column will be removed from the web console in 2.18.0 via [ARTEMIS-3397](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3397).